# Forever Do While Loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, passwords, do-while

This code keeps looping and looping. I'm using a do..while loop create a simple password checker however..
It keeps looping and looping any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
 {
    let password;
   do {
         password = prompt("Enter the code");
      } while (password.toLowerCase() !== "jude" || "joel");
  }
```

Comment: because you dont do anything to stop that looping, make them equal and it will stop

Answer (score 1):

This:

```js
password.toLowerCase() !== "jude" || "joel"
```

is not actually what you think it does. It will always evaluate to `true`, since `"joel"`, when coerced to a boolean, is `true` (See [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values).

Demonstration:

```js
const str = "joel";

if (str) {
  console.log("true!");
} else {
  console.log("false!");
}
```

You have to do the comparison again:

```js
let password;
do {
    password = prompt("Enter the code");
} while (password.toLowerCase() !== "jude" || password.toLowerCase() !== "joel");
```

Since you're only checking whether the password in lower case is equal or not (pointed out by [MikeM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565512/mikem)), you can also just assign the result of the prompt after being converted to lower case to `password`. This means we will only need to convert to lowercase once:

```js
let password;
do {
    password = prompt("Enter the code").toLowerCase();
} while (password !== "jude" || password !== "joel");
```

Or even better, store the valid passwords in an array and check whether it includes the password:

```js
let password;
do {
    password = prompt("Enter the code");
} while (!["jude", "joel"].includes(password.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: I'm finding that the do while here is still looping after the condition has been satisfied. I'm able to avoid it by using `break;` with a while.

Comment: Works now! I was too focused on testing valid passwords to have realised that was the cause! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way that avoids the do while is to use a while with a `break;` inside.

```js
let password;
while (true) {
    password = prompt("Enter the code");
    if (["jude", "joel"].includes(password.toLowerCase())) {
        break;
    }
}
```